# How can I hijack \ takeover a download request over the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, request

Scenario:

1) I'm inside Dropbox Cloud.

2) I have a few files there.

3) I click "Download" for a specific file.

4) The file is immediately downloaded in the browser.

- Let's review section 4)

I would like to hijack the download request so I can manipulate it to "download" \ "send the file" to a local server of mine rather than directly downloading the file.

I can think of a few ways to do that:

1) A small chrome extension that runs in the background and query the DOM in order to assemble the download link and then send it to my server so I can send a get request to it.

2) Parsing the html page with a small web scraper and do the exact thing I would do as section 1)

3) Use Dropbox API V2 in order to get a url link for a specific file or a specific container with its links and then initiate a download request whenever I choose to.

Yet, I would like to know if there is a way to directly takeover the initiated download request on the browser, so I can route it to another server of mine.

- I'm asking this because eventually I would like to transform the file on my side and only then to once again initiate the download request (via a hidden form with a listener let's say) to the one who initiated the download

A flow image to be more clear:

[image: flow]

Comment: you should use the dropbox api. the direct download link could be linked to the current session and maybe does not work on your server.

Comment: I sincerely hope not. At least not via direct download. The idea that a file could be interfered with _after_ I have clicked download by a _third party_ is scary.